# BigCommerce - Hello World App - Callback URLs

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to install the BigCommerce Hello World App from [bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex). When I try to install the app in my trial store it displays the index of the app folder.
[image: Index of the app folder].

I think it has something to do with the callback URLs.
[image: Callback URLs]

The instructions are not clear as what to enter here so I entered:

- Auth Callback URL: https://localhost/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex
- Load Callback: URL:
  https://localhost/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex
- Uninstall Callback URL:
  https://localhost/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

index.php is located in bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

What am I supposed to enter for the Callback URLs?

Also, this is what I entered in the .env file for the environment variables.

BC_AUTH_SERVICE and BC_CALLBACK_URL
[image: environment variables]

**Update:** Ok, I was able to get the index.php to load by default.
In Apache24/conf/httpd.conf, I changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride FileInfo", uncommented "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so", and in the .htaccess file, in the root of the project, I removed the "/" that proceeded index.php so it now says "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]". The "/" needed to be removed because the project was not in the root directory.

Now I get two errors. It looks like this project was written to be in the root directory, so I put it in the root, put the "/" back in .htaccess, updated the URLs, and I still get the same two errors.

[image: ResourceNotFoundException]

[image: NotFoundHttpException]

Comment: Why do suspect the callback URLs to be the cause of the problem? The problem is that your web server isn't configured to execute PHP files. Anyway you need to replace `localhost` with a DNS name or IP address of the server, so the clients can reach it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I tested the web server with a test .php file that uses curl authentication so I know it works. Also, I am trying to install it in my trial store, from my computer, where my web server is set up, localhost works fine.

Comment: The fact that you see a directory listing including an `index.php` file proves that your web server, at least for this directory, is not set up to execute PHP files.

Comment: When I go directly to localhost it displays "It works!" and that is what is in index.php.

Comment: . . . but I see what you are saying. If it works for localhost, why doesn't it work for localhost/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to say. What happens if you click it?

Comment: The file in the root is not index.php, it is index.html. I need to find out how to get the index.php to run automatically. In the mean time, I hope to get some input about the Callback URLs, because when I click on index.php in that index, I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Callback URLs need to include the path to /load and /auth/callback.

- Auth Callback URL: https://localhost/auth/callback
- Load Callback: URL: https://localhost/load
- Uninstall Callback URL: https://localhost/uninstall

They are not paths to a folder, they are paths to a resource. That's why the error is ResourceNotFound.

The Callback URL in .env needs to be:
BC_CALLBACK_URL=https://localhost/auth/callback

Answer (score 0):

I will so many times I Will use every possibility but error was not solved let me know how you solve this error in your case.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nLKu.jpg

```
Here My .env file : 
BC_AUTH_SERVICE=https://login.bigcommerce.com
BC_CLIENT_ID=My client id
BC_CLIENT_SECRET=My secret id
BC_CALLBACK_URL=https://localhost/bigcommerce/callback/load

Here My Server path in dev tools file: 
Auth Callback URL - more info 
https://localhost/bigcommerce/callback
Load Callback URL - more info 
https://localhost/bigcommerce/load
Uninstall Callback URL - more info 
https:/localhost/bigcommerce/uninstall

Let me folder structure of Silex 
My localhost is Right now [ HTTPS ]  : https://localhost/bigcommerce/index.php
```

Answer (score -1):

Add .htaccess in your project Root directory with this code

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

# only rewrite if the requested file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

# pass the rest of the request into index.php to handle
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Prevent the web from seeing the readme.md just to be safe
RewriteRule ^README\.MD$ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Don't dump code. Explain the OP's problem and explain how your answer solves this.

Comment: There is a .htaccess file in the root with that exact contents.